# Вывод значений в одну строку

Tags: dart

В языке **Kotlin** или **Java** есть функции **print()**, которая осуществляет вывод значения без перевода на новую строку и **println()**, которая осуществляет вывод значения с переводом на новую строку.

В языке **Dart** функции **print()** осуществляет вывод значения с переводом на новую строку.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
 print(i);
}
```

Как вывести в одну строку? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению в Dart 2 посчитали что, такой функционал не нужен и не стали добавлять его в язык ([документация по Print](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/print.html)). Обойти это можно так:

```
print('i' * 5 ); //iiiii
```

В Dart 1 была возможность обойти это: пример @AndrewGoroshko, насколько я понимаю теперь он используется в Stream (аналог парадигмы ReactiveX).

Comment: Спасибо Вам MiT большое!

Comment: @Anton `print('i' * 5 );` возможно поможет такой способ!

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `stdout`:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
 stdout.write(i);
}
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073217/print-without-a-newline-in-dart) упоминается подобная проблема. Либо `stderr` но это вообще в [документации](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/stderr.html) идет как логирование ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Andrew Goroshko большое!

Comment: вы пожалуйста определитесь с принятием ответа :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko человек запаниковал)

Comment: @MiT, да я уже понял что решения принимались молниеносно))